# Filtering Array, some working, one not

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, filter

I have built a sortable list that has four selects to sort through.  The idea is if you pick one dropdown option and there are no matches with the other dropdowns, they vanish from the other dropdowns.  That part works perfectly, however now the problem is the 'Services' dropdown doesn't appear to be working at all.  I'm checking my datatype and it is, or at least should be an array.  what am I missing?

Thanks!

```
        <div id="providers">


          <select id="type" class="options"><option value="">Select Provider Type</option><option value='3'>Youth Empowerment Services</option><option value='2'>Child and Family Services</option><option value='4'>Intellectual or Developmental Disabilities</option><option value='5'>Substance Abuse Managed Service</option></select>        
                        <select id="services" class="options"><option value="">Select Service Type</option><option value="111">Service A</option><option value="112">Service B</option><option value="113">Service C</option><option value="114">Service D</option><option value="115">Service E</option><option value="116">Service F</option><option value="117">Service G</option><option value="118">Service H</option><option value="119">Service I</option></select>        

                        <select id="location" class="options"><option value="">Select Location Type</option><option value="201">Location A</option><option value="202">Location B</option><option value="203">Location C</option></select>  

        <select id="language" class="options"><option value="">Select Language Type</option><option value='17'>Spanish</option><option value='18'>Vietnamese</option><option value='16'>English</option></select>    
        <button id="reset-search">Reset Filter</button>


        <ul id="results" class="list">









            <li class="card" data-type="[5]" data-service="[117, 118, 119]" data-location="[201, 201, 201]" data-language="[16]">
              <h1>Provider C</h1>
              <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/substance-abuse-managed-service/" rel="tag">Substance Abuse Managed Service</a><br /><br />
              <strong>Language:</strong><br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a><br /><br />

                      <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                            <ins>Service G</ins><br />
                            Location A<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service H</ins><br />
                            Location A<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service I</ins><br />
                            Location A<br /><br />

            </li>








            <li class="card" data-type="[4]" data-service="[114, 115, 116]" data-location="[201, 202, 203]" data-language="[16, 17]">
              <h1>Provider B</h1>
              <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/intellectual-or-developmental-disabilities/" rel="tag">Intellectual or Developmental Disabilities</a><br /><br />
              <strong>Language:</strong><br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a>, <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/spanish/" rel="tag">Spanish</a><br /><br />

                      <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                            <ins>Service D</ins><br />
                            Location A<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service E</ins><br />
                            Location B<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service F</ins><br />
                            Location C<br /><br />

            </li>








            <li class="card" data-type="[2]" data-service="[111, 112, 113]" data-location="[201, 202, 203]" data-language="[16, 18]">
              <h1>Provider A</h1>
              <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/child-and-family-services/" rel="tag">Child and Family Services</a><br /><br />
              <strong>Language:</strong><br />
              <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a>, <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/vietnamese/" rel="tag">Vietnamese</a><br /><br />

                      <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                            <ins>Service A</ins><br />
                            Location A<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service B</ins><br />
                            Location B<br /><br />

                            <ins>Service C</ins><br />
                            Location C<br /><br />

            </li>

        </ul>  
        </div>

        <script>
        jQuery(function($) {  


        $("select.options").change(function(){

            var type        = $('#type').val();
            var services    = $('#services').val();
            var location    = $('#location').val();
            var language    = $('#language').val();

            type        = parseInt(type);
            services    = parseInt(services);
            location    = parseInt(location);
            language    = parseInt(language);

        if ( $( ".variable" ).length ) {

          $(".card.variable").hide().each(function() {

            var card = $(this);  
            var typearray     = eval($(this).attr("data-type"));
            var servicesarray = eval($(this).attr("data-services"));
            var locationarray = eval($(this).attr("data-location"));
            var languagearray = eval($(this).attr("data-language"));

            if (type) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(type, typearray) != -1)  {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }  

            if (services) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(services, servicesarray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                }; 
            }

            if (location) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(location, locationarray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }

            if (language) {  
                if (jQuery.inArray(language, languagearray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }


          });
        } else {
          $(".card").hide().each(function() {
               alert(services); 
            var card = $(this);  
            var typearray     = eval($(this).attr("data-type"));
            var servicesarray = eval($(this).attr("data-services"));
            var locationarray = eval($(this).attr("data-location"));
            var languagearray = eval($(this).attr("data-language"));

            if (type) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(type, typearray) != -1)  {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }  

            if (services) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(services, servicesarray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };

                }; 
            }

            if (location) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(location, locationarray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }

            if (language) {  
                if (jQuery.inArray(language, languagearray) != -1) {
                    $(card).show();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("variable")) {
                        $(card).addClass('variable');
                    };
                };
            }


          });
        };


            var itemtype= "";
            var itemservices= "";
            var itemlocation= "";
            var itemlanguage= "";
            $( ".variable" ).each( function() {
                itemtype = $(this).data('type');
                itemservices = $(this).data('service');
                itemlocation = $(this).data('location');
                itemlanguage = $(this).data('language');
            });

             console.log(itemtype);
             var excludetypesarray         = eval(itemtype);
             var excludeservicearray      = eval(itemservices);
             var excludelocationarray     = eval(itemlocation);
             var excludelanguagearray     = eval(itemlanguage);


          $("select.options#type option").hide().each(function() {
                var checktype = $(this).val();
                var checktype = parseInt(checktype);
                var select = $(this);
                if (jQuery.inArray(checktype, excludetypesarray) != -1) { 
                    $(select).show();   
                }
          });

          $("select.options#services option").hide().each(function() {
                var checktype = $(this).val();
                var checktype = parseInt(checktype);
                var select = $(this);
                if (jQuery.inArray(checktype, excludeservicearray) != -1) { 
                    $(select).show();   
                }
          });

          $("select.options#location option").hide().each(function() {
                var checktype = $(this).val();
                var checktype = parseInt(checktype);
                var select = $(this);
                if (jQuery.inArray(checktype, excludelocationarray) != -1) { 
                    $(select).show();   
                }
          });

          $("select.options#language option").hide().each(function() {
                var checktype = $(this).val();
                var checktype = parseInt(checktype);
                var select = $(this);
                if (jQuery.inArray(checktype, excludelanguagearray) != -1) { 
                    $(select).show();   
                }
          });


        });


            $("#reset-search").on('click', function(){
                $(".card").each(function() {
                   $(this).show();
                    $(this).removeClass('variable');
                });
                $("select.options option").each(function() {

                   $(this).show(); 
                });
            });

        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

my own stupid fault.  Gotta doublecheck those variable names